# what's the difference between set_position('center') and set_position('zero') in terms of ax.spines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a plot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13430231/10825607).

I studied the examples come from [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/spine_placement_demo.html).

What I have known is

1. left spine could play a role of y axis in a Cartesian coordinate plane.
2. bottom spine could play a role of x axis in a Cartesian coordinate plane.
3. `set_position()` could shift spines.

My question is what the difference between putting a spine (say, 'left') to 'center' and 'zero'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
y = 2 * np.sin(x)

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax.set_title('centered spines')
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax.set_title('zeroed spines')
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If `0` is in the center of your plot, there obviously is no difference between `"zero"` and `"center"`. Use non-symmetric data like `x = np.linspace(-1.5, np.pi, 100)` to see the difference.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest would you please describe a scenario where 0 is not the center, besides the examples in matplotlib site ('spines at data (1, 2)' and 'spines at axes (0.6, 0.1)')

Comment: An example is the one I mentionned in the first comment, `x = np.linspace(-1.5, np.pi, 100)`.